# Tkinter only shows image in the last label created

Tags: python, tkinter

This is the code I wrote

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from scripts.values import readFruitPrices
from scripts.stock import getCurrentFruits

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.iconbitmap("assets/kitsune.ico")
root.title("Blox Fruits")


def fruitLabel(root, fruitName="rocket", width = 75, height = 75, relief = "ridge"):
    global fruitIcon

    frame = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=2, relief=relief)

    fruitIcon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("assets/"+fruitName+".png").resize( (width,height) ))

    fruitPrice = readFruitPrices()[fruitName]
    fruitPriceString = "$"+f'{fruitPrice:,}'  #puts commas as the thousands seperator

    picLabel = tk.Label(frame, image=fruitIcon)
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=fruitName+"\n"+fruitPriceString)

    picLabel.pack()
    label.pack()

    return frame
    

cFruits = getCurrentFruits()
fruitLabels = list()

for fruit in cFruits:
    fruitLabels.append(fruitLabel(root, fruit.name.lower()))

for i, l in enumerate(fruitLabels):
    l.grid(row=0,column=i)


root.mainloop()
```

`getCurrentFruits()` returns a list of fruits, which have a name and a price if that's relevant.

What is happening is that only the last fruit shows the image, the others are blank (as seen  bellow)

[image: This is what's happening]

I have checked and the files for all the fruits do exist and are correctly named. In fact, no matter the fruit or how many fruits there are, only the last one ever shows an image.
What could be going on?

Comment: Add `picLabel.image = fruitIcon`. The `global fruitIcon` only keeps a reference to the last image so the rest are deleted from memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: Add it where, inside the function?

Comment: Inside the function just before the return statement

Comment: Ay it worked tysm